# How is best way to use Java Optional class for this example?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to best implement the Optional class in this java example, for when there is not an "Exclusion" field present (when it's null I dont want an exception)

```java
List<Exclusion> exclusions = offer
    .getSources()
    .stream()
    .map(Source::getExclusion)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I posted this short example at https://www.online-java.com/Wb4gxPODfI

Any ideas?

Comment: Can any `sources` be `null`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, `Optional<T>` is usually useful in interfaces; it'd need to be *returned from* `getExclusion`. In this case, what you really need to do is filter the stream after calling `getExclusion`. You can do so with `Objects::nonNull` from `java.util.Objects`:

```java
List<Exclusion> exclusions = offer
    .getSources()
    .stream()
    .map(Source::getExclusion)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(Note that I find your question a little unclear: if the problem is that the *exclusion* is `null`, then the filter should come after the `map`; if the problem is that the *source* is `null`, then it should come before. If `null` can come from either, then you can filter both before and after the `map`.)